# static IP for container in docker swarm

Tags: docker, static, ip, containers, swarm

I'm new in docker and I have a simple question.
I have 3 hosts running a docker swarm with the following ip's:

- `192.168.0.52`
- `192.168.0.53`
- `192.168.0.54`

Also, I've created a http service with a published `port:8080`. As expected, service it's available at all hosts ip's (ex: `192.168.0.52:8080`).
Is it possible to assign a static IP Address to the service(for example `192.168.0.254`) and be able to reach it from any computer from my local network ? (`192.168.0.0/24`). 
This way I should have high availability for my service; if the host with the service goes down, it should be started on another host, but keep the same IP.
Thanks,
Alex